# Is it possible to delete the Minecraft folder on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I'm trying to fix a Null Pointer Exception I'm getting when running Minecraft on my Mac. Some instructions I've found said that I needed to do two things:

- Uninstall/Reinstall Java
- 'Nuke' the Minecraft folder

I've done the first, but I am unsure how to delete the Minecraft folder.

So how can I delete (nuke) a Minecraft folder?

Comment: I think it's just asking you to delete the entire folder.

Comment: Well uninstalling Java and reinstalling the latest isn't really going to do much. Do as recommended Nuke the whole minecraft folder. It sounds like its become corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft resides in the Application Support directory in your library. To delete it, Open Finder, press `Shift-Command-G`, and type `~/Library/Application Support/` in the dialog that appears. Then you can do as you wish with your Minecraft installation.